# PHP: replace string with jolly char inside

Tags: php, regex, replace, char

I need help for regex in php... "jolly char" in string replace. This is what I have now:

```
$String = str_replace('<audio type="soundcloud">'.
    '[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/',
    '<audio type="soundcloud">', $String);

$String = str_replace(' params="color=ff6600&auto_play=false&'.      
    'show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]</audio>',
    '</audio>', $String);
```

Input is:

```
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/audio_id" params="color=ff6600&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]
```

Output is:

```
<audio type="soundcloud">audio_id</audio>
```

and that's okay only if `param` remains unchanged (I wish to match any `param` value)

Now, I'm trying to solve it with regular expressions.

This is what I would like to replace:

```
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/audio_id" params="*]
```

...in order to have this:

```
<audio type="soundcloud">audio_id</audio>
```

(I don't need to save any parameters, for the moment)

So, I have to DELETE any char between params=" and ].

Can someone help me?
I promise I will study, before next dumb question! :)

---

EDIT #1:

I apologize for my unclear question, and I try to explain it in another way.
This is what I have in input:

```
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123456789" params="color=ff6600&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]
```

This is what I need as output:

```
<audio type="soundcloud">123456789</audio>
```

...where:

- "123456789" changes and has to be saved.
- I have to del all text between "params" and "]" (included).

I think I need a FINAL marker, so I have to write "params" somewhere in the regex...

---

EDIT #2:

This is my last attempt:

```
$String = preg_replace('\<audio type="soundcloud"\>\[soundcloud url=\"https\:\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/([^"]+).*.\<\/audio\>', '<audio type="soundcloud">\1</audio>', $String);
```

...it works in the regex101.com demo, but it doesn't in my page.

---

EDIT #3:

Fixed! 
Of course your answers were right... I got in trouble for two missing slashes in edit #2!

This is the right version:

```
$String = preg_replace('/\<audio type=\"soundcloud\"\>\[soundcloud url=\"https\:\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/([^"]+).*.\<\/audio\>/', '<audio type="soundcloud">\1</audio>', $String);
```

Thanks very much for your help... and Happy New Year!

Comment: Okay, i'll take your word on this... But could you please edit your question and be clear about what is the input and what is the expected output ?

Comment: Mh... I think you're right! :)
I've just edited my question, sorry.

Comment: Did you check my answer ? `I have to write "params" somewhere in the regex` what does that mean, do you want to capture it too ?

Comment: It works, it's hidden, check the source code of the web page...

Comment: Yep, now I understand your code... the quote (") is the final marker.
However, it doesn't work: the output is blank.
Now, I'm wondering if the problem is elsewhere... I'm sure it's not strip_tags's fault (it's the first thing I've checked), but this afternoon I will scan all the code.
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Again, the output is there... to see it check the html source code or use `echo htmlentities($ouptput);`...

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will be `\[soundcloud url="https://api\.soundcloud\.com/tracks/([^"]*?)"([^\]]*?)\]`

and you can use `preg_replace` like this

```
$String = preg_replace('/\\[soundcloud url="https:\/\/api\\.soundcloud\\.com\/tracks\/([^"]*?)"([^\]]*?)\\]/',
    '<audio type="soundcloud">$\1</audio>')
```

Comment: Mh... this doesn't work... "audio_id" should be ONLY what is between: 

    [soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" 

AND 

    params="*]

...so I have to write "params" somewhere in the regex

Comment: No you don't. This regex matches everything up to `...tracks/` and groups everything between that and the quotation marks as the `audio_id`. Then after the quotation marks anything that isn't a square bracket (`]`) is matched and tossed, including `params` and anything else that might follow the `url` attribute. Granted I haven't tested this `preg_replace` but you should read into regex to understand what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

Well, you can use the following pattern wich extracts the `audio_id`, then replaces the whole input with `<audio type="soundcloud">\1</audio>` where `\1` is the extracted `audio_id`:

```
/.*?tracks\/([^"]+).*/
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/xP9rU5)

Explanation:

```
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  tracks                   'tracks'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?
    $input = '[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/audio_id" params="*]';

    $pattern = '/.*?tracks\/([^"]+).*/';

    $replacement= '<audio type="soundcloud">\1</audio>';

    $ouptput = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);

    echo htmlentities($ouptput);
?>
```

[`Live DEMO`](http://codepad.org/7hCbIf5g)

**HTML parsing**

As a final word, I don't know if that's the only case you're using regex to parse an HTML code, but please consider using a more appropriate tool for that... There are many HTML parsers outthere (one of the best is [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/))...

If you still asking why, check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1519058).